# Web Server in Command Line

Tags: php

I'm trying to have a login page where it logs all login attempts to another command line file which is `Login_Server.php`.

My current method is a bit of an "outcast" because, basically when you login it'll insert in a database `Whoever logged in from 127.0.0.1`, and my Login_Server.php looks like this:

```
<?php
  echo "Server Listening \n";
  while(1) {
    while($row) {
      echo $row['login_msg'] . "\n";
      DELETE login_msg from sql
    }
    sleep(1);
  }
?>
```

So it's not a good way to do it. Is there another way as simple as this that uses sockets, or something more 'efficient'?

Comment: this is not even a valid syntax. And you didn't use `socket_*` functions at all.

Comment: Are you able to use node.js or something similar for this? PHP is a synchronous language so is not the best for doing this kind of thing, where as node is an event-based asynchronous language which can sit there happily and wait for your messages to appear without running an infinite loop like this

Comment: @Raptor woah bro calm down I used it as an example.

Comment: @Scrowler uh no I can use Python tho!

Comment: what about `server log`, like apache log OR nginx log.